# check if there is anything next to the item in board (2D array)

Tags: c++, arrays

Hey I'm making simple console game in C++. We have pawns on board (I made it using 2D dynamic array). I want to check if there is space to move our pawn. My simplest and best idea would be if I could check every square next to the pawn. The problem, however, arises when the pawn is in the corner of the board.
(x-1,y), (x, y+1) , (x+1, y) , (x, y-1)  [this means every field around our pawn]. My board is 2D dynamic array. So if I check field e.g. array[-1][0] (this means field x: -1, y: 0) of course it goes out of memory range. And my question is, Is it good if I go outside this range anyway but I will make a condition in case of this error?

Comment: Your question does not include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 
Please show your own attempt first. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67357283/edit) your question to include your code, sample input and output, and any error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check whether index is in bounds:

```
if (x >= 0 && x < SIZE_X && y >= 0 && y < SIZE_Y)
    return array[x][y];
else
    return nullptr;
```

Alternatively use try/catch:

```
try
{
    return array[x][y];
}
catch (out_of_range e)
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `try/catch` for a regular program flow control.

Comment: @zkoza can you tell me why ?

Comment: Because exception handling it is VERY costly. Exceptions are for exceptional case where you really don't know what to do and decide to pass the decision up the stack frame. A typical scenario is for a library to signal that it cannot accomplish some task, and then the exception object will pass the information what and why has happened.

Comment: Also, out-of-bounds errors CAN result in exceptions being thrown, but more likely you will be hit be a segmentation fault. And then nothing can save your program from a sudden death.  To count on exceptions in the above code, you'd need to write the class for array yourself or rely on its reliable documentation.

Comment: But the main argument is this: exceptions are for unusual and/or difficult to predict program flow paths. Here you CAN predict what and when will happen with 100% accuracy. In such cases use standard flow control mechanisms, like `if`, `for` etc.

Comment: the exception in the answer and the discussion in comments is rather misleading. I am not aware of any "array" type that throws exception from its `operator[]`. Wether the use of exceptions is good or bad is secondary, it simply doesnt work.